# How to obtain the Position on the screen (Vector2) of the Position of an object in the world (Vector3)?

Tags: matrix, transformation, screen, projection-matrix, position

I have been searching around for a solution to this but still haven't been able to use it or find it, the thing is i need the Screen Position of an object that is being seen, for this i have three elements:

- The Camera Position (Vector3).
- The Object Position (Vector3).

Both Vector3 are in the context of the world.

And that's kinda it, i have found some solutions than are very clear but requires additional stuff than i don't know/can't obtain by the context.

I have found some other very intensive math solutions around but they are way beyond my math level so i prefer to ask.

**How to obtain the Position on the screen (Vector2) of the Position of an object in the world (Vector3)?**

If the answer can come in the shape of a C# function even better.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Are you using Unity? If not, you'll need a few more items: 1) the camera's facing direction (and up direction, though we can make a reasonable guess about that one), 2) the screen/window resolution or aspect ratio, 3) if using a perspective camera, the field of view angle, or if using an orthographic camera, the height of the image plane.

Comment: 1) I am in fact not using unity.
2) You may assume use of .Net 8, Stride3d if it helps.
3) Perspective camera is in use indeed.

Comment: Do you have access to data for points 1, 2, and the FoV value for point 3?

Comment: what i said is what i have, but also I have a value for distance between the camera and the object position, and i think i get the field of view too, and although i kinda manage to obtain a functional result, for some reason if i get away or get closer i stop getting the right conversion, i am not certain if my answer was what you were looking at but i hope it helps.

Comment: If you don't have these pieces of information, then you do not have what you need to solve the problem. Find ways to get this information first, then we can help you.